# GCP Cloud DNS won't resolve Namecheap dns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, namecheap

Problem : Google DNS won't resolve the Namecheap DNS I bought to my instance.

Config :

[image: CloudDnsNameCheap]

What I've followed : https://www.typeeighty.com/add-domain-google-cloud/

What I've tried : I've tried to change cloud DNS a bunch of times all to no avail, is there' anything obvious I am missing in what I need to configure?

Comment: **1.** Please add unresolved DNS requests to your question **2.** How many hours ago have you configured DNS? **3.** Is it possible for you to share your domain name? **4.** Have you checked [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart)?

Comment: Your CNAME is not formatted correctly. What is `my.domain`? What is `my.doomain`? They are not valid TLDs (top-level domain) therefore global DNS will not work for those domain names.

Comment: Thanks @SerhiiRohoza.

Turns out, my frontend was listening only on port 80, not 443 that firefox was originally automatically searching for. I am going to implement SSL, update my frontend and hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: Please post an answer to make it useful for community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was confirmed by *@eternal_atom* in the comment section there's no issue related to DNS configuration and everything works as expected.

**The cause of this issue** is behavior of modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc.) to automatically redirect requests like `my.domain` to `https://my.domain`.

**To avoid such situation** during testing you should use `http://my.domain` instead of `my.domain`. Also, you could use command line utils like `dig` and `curl` for troubleshooting.